# Change ListView's item position from CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

In my application there is a ListView where I've put some data on it from a CustomAdapter where I changed the item's desing to one I've made with a button in it, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:padding="15dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Button" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my CustomAdapter:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> items;

    CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String[] items) {
        super(context, 0, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.items = Arrays.asList(items);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (CustomAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final Holder finalHolder = holder;
        final String item = items.get(position);

        finalHolder.textView.setText(item);
        finalHolder.button.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finalHolder.layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                    //this is how I've tried and haven't worked
                    items.remove(position);
                    items.add(items.size()-1, item);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        );

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class Holder{
        LinearLayout layout;
        TextView textView;
        Button button;
    }
}
```

I need that when you click in the button of one of the item in the list, this item go to the last position in the list (with its color changed).

Comment: Do not store Collection(items) by your own when you are deriving from ArrayAdapter<>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ListView lv = getListView();
setContentView(lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
         tmp = lv.get(0);
         lv.set(0, list.get(position));
         lv.set(position,tmp);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Also you can change position of listview by using setSelection

```
ListView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: This won't do it. My need is that this event happens when I click in the item button but from inside the adapter. Because in my original program i have some extra tests in the adapter.